# Batched Gather/GatherND

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was wondering if there is a way to do the following in TensorFlow, using `gather_nd` or something similar.

I have two tensors:

- `values` with shape `[128, 100]`,
- `indices` with shape `[128, 3]`,

where each row of `indices` contains indices along the second dimension of `values` (for that same row). I want to index `values` using `indices`. For example, I want something that does this (using loose notation to represent tensors):

```
values  = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
indices = [[2, 3, 6], 
           [0, 2, 3]]
batched_gather(values, indices) = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
```

This op will go through each row of `values` and `indices` and perform a gather on the `values` row using the `indices` row.

Is there a simple way to do this in TensorFlow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this qualifies as "simple", but you can use `gather_nd` for this:

```
def batched_gather(values, indices):
    row_indices = tf.range(0, tf.shape(values)[0])[:, tf.newaxis]
    row_indices = tf.tile(row_indices, [1, tf.shape(indices)[-1]])
    indices = tf.stack([row_indices, indices], axis=-1)
    return tf.gather_nd(values, indices)
```

Explanation: The idea is to construct index vectors such as `[0, 1]` meaning "the value in the 0th row and 1st column".
The column indices are already given in the `indices` argument to the function.
The row indices are a simple progression from 0 to e.g. 128 (in your example), but are repeated (tiled) in accordance with the number of column indices for each row (3 in your example; could hardcode this instead of using `tf.shape` if this number is fixed).
The row and column indices are then stacked to produce the index vectors. In your example, the resulting indices would be

```
array([[[0, 2],
        [0, 3],
        [0, 6]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]]])
```

and `gather_nd` produces the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! That does actually do what I need. I was wondering though if there might also be a more efficient way to do this that avoids creating the intermediate range, and tiled tensors. It kind of feels like an unnecessary inefficiency.